# Problems in code, need assistance

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a messages app with **parse** and I have just started some code.  But there are some problems with it working in Xcode 6.4. Could someone help. I'm also having problems with the **class section**. I'm a beginner.

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageTableView: UITableView!

var messageArray: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("Object has been saved.")
    }
    self.messageTableView.delegate = self
    self.messageTableView.dataSource = self

    messageArray.append("Test 1")
    messageArray.append("test 2")
    messageArray.append("test 3")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView , cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = self.messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.messageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableview(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return messageArray.count
}
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problems.

Comment: Hey Jack! Tip 101 both for a new programmer and a new Stack user : explain your problem WELL. Do some "rubber duck debugging" first, come here with a specific "I need to do X in class Y.... I found how to do Z, but I can't get the gaznickel to bamboozle properly"... something like that. Often simply explaining your problem, you get an idea of how to solve it. And on Stack, if you don't do that, your question will be poorly received anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to display `messageArray` into `tableView` but your delegates methods are not conforming `UITableViewDataSource` protocol so replace your methods with this methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.messageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messageArray.count
}
```

and your complete code will be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTableView: UITableView!

    var messageArray: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.messageTableView.delegate = self
        self.messageTableView.dataSource = self

        messageArray.append("Test 1")
        messageArray.append("test 2")
        messageArray.append("test 3")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.messageArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messageArray.count
    }

}
```

And [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=79018336912929292422) is your sample project.